# Wall power socket outlet: square or sine wave?

Tags: waveform

Power station alternators, do they produce pure sine wave power? If so, then any rotating generator must produce pure sine wave power. Irrespective of the kind of AVR it has. Is this correct?

Answer (score 6):

Utility power generators produce three-phase sine power.  One reason for this is that the power is constant within a cycle.  That means there is no torque ripple on the generator shaft.  If there was, these large machines would be vibrating themselves into pieces.

Another reason for sine waves is that there is no harmonic content.  If the generator puts out 60 Hz, then 60 Hz is the highest frequency that the rest of the transmission system has to deal with.  Any other waveshape than sine would contain other frequencies.  This would complicate parts of the transmission system, especially the transformers.

That said, while the power voltage is ideally sinusoidal, in practice it's not perfect, of course.  Most of the reason is that loads don't always draw sinusoidal current.  Think of a full wave bridge, for example.  It draws current in spikes at the tips of the waves.  Since the impedance of the power line isn't zero, this non-sinusoidal current draw causes some non-sinusoidal voltage.  Since non-sinusoidal voltage is undesirable, there are regulations about how much the current draw is allowed to vary from sinusoidal for high power loads.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense Olin and I appreciate your responce

Answer (score 4):

> do they produce pure sine wave power?

They produce an output voltage that is fairly sinusoidal but, because power depends on the load and the load can take fairly non-sinusoidal current (bridge rectifiers for example), the power is not as sinusoidal as the voltage produced.

And, sinewave voltages are produced because there are no higher order harmonics that would make motors and transformers significantly less efficient (or more costly). Also, if power transmission lines were fed with square waves, the harmonics would interfere with long and medium wave radio transmission systems.

Comment: Thanks Andy, so if I put a crow (oscilloscope) to a power out let it would actually show a sine wave, is that correct?

Comment: Yes it should indicate a sine wave unless of course you are looking at the output of an inverter (UPS) because some of these (cheaper ones) are fairly square-ish.

Comment: Most interesting! My son is an electrician and he trying to tell me that the AVR of a generator changes the sinoidal form of the wave. I have told him that that is incorrect, as the AVR only regulates the voltage value depending of the load of the alternator

Comment: Hold on though... if the AVR does the regulating by rapidly switching, then it will introduce high-frequency harmonics in the output, the same as any switched-mode power supply or inverter would do.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple why should it?

Comment: How does an AVR work?  If it works the same way a SMPS works, then it will be driving a transistor at e.g. 50 kHz at a duty cycle sufficient to drop the voltage at the output stage by the desired amount.  But I guess you know that given that you are an EE?  So the question is, how does an AVR work?

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple it's YOU who is making noises about the AVR so you should look it up and then withdraw your imaginative comment.

Comment: If you answered the question properly the first time, I wouldn't have to. The original question said "irrespective of the kind of AVR it has" and you did not address this.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple listen, "power" transmission uses sinewave voltages for a myriad of very good reasons, (irrespective of what AVR is used). The upshot of this MUST MEAN that an AVR cannot significantly produce harmonics AND, added to this, it does not act like a bloody SMPS.

Comment: Thanks Andy, thats excactly the confirmation of my comment. Much appreciated!

Comment: @HansArwedLang well instead of thanks (always appreciated though) you should consider formally accepting the answer that best answered your question. There all useful answers of course but which one best suits the question.

Answer (score 3):

You'd tend to get pretty high quality sine waves at your house, even if the power generator produced something much closer to (for example) a square wave.

In a typical case, you have *miles* of power line running from the generator to your house. That amount of wire gives a *high* inductance. In addition, the power typically goes through at least a couple of transformers between the generator and your house. Again, this adds a great deal of inductance to the circuit.

That gives a circuit that looks something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgvPIq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In reality, you might easily have more than two transformers involved, but you get the *general* idea.

The long and short of it is that they do their best to start with a sine wave--but even if it starts with other higher frequencies mixed in, the transformers and transmission lines act like a massive low-pass filter, so by the time the "signal" comes out the wall in your house, most higher-frequencies have been removed pretty effectively (leaving a relatively pure sine wave).

In fairness, I should probably add that those long lines generally aren't shielded, so they will also act as a giant antenna. If a power line ran through an area with an extremely high level of RFI, then only a short distance to your home, it might still carry quite a bit of that interference when it reaches your house. Realistically, this is unlikely to be much (if any) of a problem for most people most of the time. At least from what I've seen, the vast majority of RFI you see on a power line will be from signals generated inside your own home (e.g., microwave ovens produce a lot of noise around 2.4 GHz). The major exception to this would be something like a thunder storm. Lightning that hits (or even comes close to) a power line can induce some pretty serious spikes on the power line (especially if they occur close to your home/office, of course).

Comment: 'Sine wave BUT ... the higher fequences have been removed'? This needs rephrasing.

Comment: @EJP: Good point.